# Cannot install YouTube app on Tecno devices (Android Go)

Tags: google-play-store, youtube, android-go, tecno

I am using a Tecno Pop 2 Power device. It runs on Android 8.1 (Oreo, Go Version). It's a new device. When I launched it, it came pre-installed with the "YouTube Go" app, which is in no way a replacement for the traditional YouTube app.

When I try to download YouTube from the Play Store, it downloads but doesn't install. Other applications install just fine, except YouTube.

Is there a way to install it? Something I'm not doing right?

Comment: Have you tried downloading and installing the Youtube apk from other stores such apkpure, apkmirror, etc?

Comment: Facing exactly the same issue with my Tecno BB2, I just think Tecno's in general have a problem