# Installing full YouTube app on Tecno phone (Android Go) failed silently

Tags: installation, youtube, android-go, tecno

I have a Tecno phone with Android 8.1.0 Go. YouTube Go is my system app, however, I grew tired of using it because of its limited features and decided to install the YouTube app. But that's when the trouble started. The app downloads until 100% and then shows that it is installing and then nothing, nothing at all back to square one, and no error is shown.

I have enough space, I have cleared data and cache for Play Store, restarted the phone, even tried APKs but still, nothing worked.

What could be the issue? The only advice I have received so far is to root the phone. What should I do? Other apps download and install just fine.

Comment: have you tried 'uninstalling' system app via [adb](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads) package manager (no root) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179575

Comment: Dupe of [Cannot install YouTube app on Tecno devices (Android Go)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/207889/44325) (but also no answers)